# Does a penalty count against a shutout in football?

Tags: football, statistics, goalkeeper

In soccer, if a goalkeeper does not save a penalty that happened during the game (as opposed to during a penalty shootout) do they still get a shutout? I was just curious because I know that in a shootout, the goals do not count.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it counts - in general, penalties during regular play are not treated any differently from other goals in in football.

Disclaimer: A "shutout" is not something defined in the [Laws of the Game](https://www.theifab.com/) (even in the [glossary](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/glossary/football-terms/)), so for a definitive answer you would need to refer to whichever organisation is collating the shutout statistics.